# How to center navigation bars logo and even links from each other?

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to get my code work for a long time and I really dont know how to put in a form so my logo would be in the middle of the navigation bar..
Also the "gaps" between my links arent even.

I tried out this medhod: [Centered navigation bar and links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405380/centered-navigation-bar-and-links)

but it didnt help.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-centered">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
            <li><a class="logo" href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About Me</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </nav>
```

and css:

```
.nav {
margin-top:200px;
height:120px;
background-color:#B0A2BC;
}

.nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}

.nav ul li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
width: 20%;
text-align:center;
}

.nav ul li a{
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
display:block;
padding:45px 80px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 21px;
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
background:url("logo1.gif");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:140px;


}

.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li.active a {
color:purple;

}
.nav-centered{
display:table;
margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are floating the li elements in your nav to the left:

```
.nav ul li{
  list-style:none;
  float:left;        <------ here.
  width: 20%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

But I might approach this another way... Your approach works if you have an even number of links on either side of the logo, but if it ever becomes unbalanced, then this won't center the way you want.

I might approach this by making a centered DIV that contains only the logo, and set it's width to the width of the logo (plus any breathing space you might want).

Then I would have two DIVs set to 50% width each, float on to the left, one to the right.  And each will have padding on its centered end equal to half of the width of the logo DIV.  Align the text to the right in the left half div, and to the left in the right-half div.

Finally, set you top-margin on the floated DIVs to a negative value equal to the somewhere around half of the centered DIV's height.

Example.  HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
  <a href="home/page/linnk.html"><img src="logoimage.png" width="200" height="200" alt="Your Logo Name" /></a>
</div>
<div class="nav left">
  <ul> ... </ul>       <----- Left-hand links here
</div>
<div class="nav right">
  <ul> ... </ul>       <----- Right-hand links here
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
div.logo {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;    <---- to center your logo DIV
  z-index: 10;     <---- make sure the logo DIV is layered above
  text-align: center;   <---- make sure your logo is centered in the DIV.  
                              Alternatively you can use padding
}

div.nav ul { ... } <---- rules to make your UL inline here
div.nav li { ... } <---- and here

div.nav {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;     <---- adjust this until it is
                                centered vertically the way you'd like
  z-index: 5;     <---- make this less than the logo DIV
}

div.nav.left {
  float:left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 120px;
}

div.nav.right {
  float:right;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 120px;
}
```

Using this approach, your logo will ALWAYS be centered, regardless of how many links you put on either side.

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained very well those things so even beginner coder like me understands it! :) I will try this out now and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the massive padding you have set on your `<a>` tags (along with being `display: block`. This:

```
.nav ul li a{
   display:block;
   padding:45px 80px;
}
```

To get the alignment you want I have made a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/15h18z33/). I removed this padding from the `<a>`'s and used the `display:table` method to achieve vertically aligned content.

The main styles changes are add `display:table;` to your `<ul>`, then adding `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` to you `<li>`'s. The `text-align:center;` was already there so that covers horizontal alignment. I also removed `<div class="nav-centered">` as it is not needed.

**Flexbox**

Another approach is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you can. Flexbox make aligning dynamic content vertically and horizontally a breeze without much code.

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b42dw5rk/).

```
.nav ul {
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Simply adding `display:flex;` and `align-items:center` to your `<ul>` will get you what you want. That's all you need... take a look at the demo...

Comment: I tried this out and it solved almost that gap problem. There should be my logo in the middle of this bar + I used that padding thing to get the text in the middle of this purple area. Sorry my coding explanations are pretty bad cos I just started to code :D Here is a pic how it looks now: http://aijaa.com/EeVzMB

Answer (score 0):

I have put your code into a jsfiddle. Do you need it to be fluid? If not check out this fiddle. * Gaps are not-even because of the padding you added as @zgood said.

https://jsfiddle.net/7vkk22w0/2/

```
.nav {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #B0A2BC;
    width: 1000px;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 20% ;
}

.nav ul li a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    background: url("logo1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 140px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li.active a {
        color: purple;
    }
.nav-centered {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div class="nav">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
        <li><a class="logo" href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">About Me</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried this out too and the logo is almost in the middle! Has it something to do with the logo of mine (height/width?) or just with the code? Here how it looks now: http://aijaa.com/QbEBqo

Comment: try to add: margin: 0 auto; to your logo selector

Comment: It didnt move it anywhere :(

Comment: Oh I took away text-align:center; and now it looks pretty much that my logo is in the middle! Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Your welcome, you can help by upvoting the given answers or select an answer ;)